# How do you expand this $ \ \left(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t+\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t^2+\sqrt 2\right) \ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ \ \left(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t+\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t^2+\sqrt 2\right) \ $

I keeping on getting $ \ t^4+t\sqrt{2}+2t^2+2\sqrt{2} \ $

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I factor $\ t^4-2 \ $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965889/how-do-i-factor-t4-2)

Comment: no it isn't. I want see how it is expanded. The root are throwing me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \ \left(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t+\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t^2+\sqrt 2\right) \ $

$= ((t)^2 - (\sqrt[4]{2})^2)(t^2 + \sqrt 2)$

$=(t^2 - \sqrt 2)(t^2 + \sqrt 2) \\= ((t^2)^2 - (\sqrt 2)^2) \\= t^4 - 2$

Remember that $(\sqrt[4]{2})^2 = (2^{\frac 14})^2 = 2^ {(\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2)}=2^{\frac 12} = \sqrt 2$

Also remember $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$. This is because $(a+b)(a-b) = a(a-b) + b(a-b) = a^2 -ab +ba - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$ (but you can just state this without proof in most cases). Just apply that twice.

Comment: Can you show more steps. That would be helpful.

Comment: Edited my answer, that help?

Comment: Not really. I am in precalculus. I need to get a more explicit explanation. Can you show me step by set your expansion. With out the short cuts?

Comment: There were practically no "shortcuts". But I've spelt it out as explicitly as I could. Remember to apply that identity that I mentioned at the end.

Comment: $\ \left(t-\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t+\sqrt[4]{2}\right)\left(t^2+\sqrt 2\right) \ $ this part confuses me shouldn't multiplying the fourth roots give 2?

Comment: No, not if you multiply only two of them. $\sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2} = \sqrt 2$. However, if you multiply four of them in a row, like so: $\sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2}$, you do indeed get $2$. Remember, it's the *one-fourth* power of $2$.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.